# How to find kafka topic RAM usage?

Tags: apache-kafka, ram

How can I monitor and check the memory usage of a Kafka topic? Are there ways to do it without installing other tools?

Answer (score 0):

Topics allocate disk space on the brokers, not (significant) RAM, due to zero-copy writes. Only temporary memory allocations would be made to handle regular client interactions, but to my knowledge JVM metrics, only show bytes in/out per topic, not memory (or CPU) per topic. There are many tools that allow you to inspect JMX beans, if you'd like to take a look yourself, but none built into Kafka, thus requiring "installing other tools"